# How can I use aws cognito with Loopback

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, loopback

I want to use Aws Cognito JavaScript SDK for sigining up User Pool through Loopback Rest Points.
User can also enter the Otp for confirming through a loopback model

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the lb "Passport component", then the passport-cognito npm module:

Here are some links:

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Third-party-login-using-Passport.html
- https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback-component-passport/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-cognito